# Unable to passing value to another activity in Android

Tags: android, xamarin-studio

I want to sent value to another activity. I'm using VS 2012 C# for developing apps. I have done lot of search from google. I have tried almost every methods. in my application `getIntent();` giving error. that is, `getIntent() does not exist in the current context.` 
I'm also not getting these below functions in my application.
`Intent sender=getIntent();`
`getApplicationContext();`

I have added all references. Help me where Am I wrong?

Comment: Did you check that all your DLL versions are compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer, I have to use below line of for getting value:

**string extraData = Intent.GetStringExtra("KeyName");**